# Go interface slice and pointer

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, struct, slice

I want to make a function on a struct which possess a slice.
My problem is : I want to use a pointer argument because I have to modify my struct content.

Here is my code :

```
type CampaignIndexMemory []CampaignIndex

type CampaignIndex struct {
    Objects []CampaignIndexObject
}

type CampaignIndexObject struct {
    //They don't really care about us
}

func (c *CampaignIndexMemory) setCampaignIndex(object CampaignIndex) {

    valueSet := false
    for i,_ := range c {
        if c[i].Objects[0].ID == object.Objects[0].ID {
            c[i] = object
            valueSet = false
            break
        }
    }
    if valueSet {
        c = append(c, object)
    }
}
```

I'm from the Java world (I'm deeply sorry) so maybe my way of proceeding wrong.

With this code, the compilation is in error and says "unresolved reference" on my "Objects" attribute.

My question is simple : What's going on ?

Thanks for your help, your time and your kindness :)

Comment: _"I want to make a function on a struct which possess a slice."_ But your receiver is not a `struct`, it's a `*CampaignIndexMemory`, i.e. a pointer to a slice of `CampaignIndex`es.

Comment: I just transformed my type into struct and it works well. Thanks.
This is my new code :

       type CampaignIndexMemory struct {indexes []CampaignIndex}

And I just have to replace all my c[i] by c.indexes[i]

Answer (score 0):

Methods are defined on types. `CampaignIndexMemory` is not a `struct` but a `type`. The type is "slice of `CampaignIndex`".

From [documentation about slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices)

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one
>   slice to another, both refer to the same array. If a function takes a
>   slice argument, changes it makes to the elements of the slice will be
>   visible to the caller, analogous to passing a pointer to the
>   underlying array.

Which implies your receiver for method `setCampaignIndex` could be a `slice` rather than a pointer to a slice. The changes will be applied to the caller.

```
func (c CampaignIndexMemory) setCampaignIndex(object CampaignIndex) {
```

Pointers to a slice points to the [slice header](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader) so I guess the error you got is because slice header does not contain a `Object` field.